# Getting links to have /

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to get all my links except for the last link to have a / at the end of them.

This is the code that I'm using

```
 while( $result = mysql_fetch_object($query) ){
        $page = new Page($result->id);
        $page->setFromDatabase();
        $str.='<ul>';
        $str.=      '<li>';
        $str.=          '<a href="">'.$page->title.'</a>';
        $str.=      '</li>';
        $str.='</ul>';

    }
```

If there is any further information that I need to give please let me know

Comment: I don't wee where you are trying to add the slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$query` is actually a result resource:

```
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($query);
$i = 1;
$str .= '<ul>';
while( $result = mysql_fetch_object($query) ){
    $page = new Page($result->id);
    $page->setFromDatabase();
    $str .=      '<li>';
    $str .=          '<a href="">'.$page->title.'</a>' . ($i < $numRows ? ' / ' : '');
    $str .=      '</li>';
    $i++;
}
$str.='</ul>';
```

I also changed your `<ul>` tag to be outside of the loop - I'm sure that's what you were going for instead of making an unordered list for *each link*...

You should also [read up on choosing a proper MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: I tried what you said and I still got a / on the last link

Comment: @user3656554 Use my edit and try again. Start with `$i = 1` and not `$i = 0`

Answer (score -1):

Use mysql_num_rows to determine the number of rows in the resultset and use that to detect when you are on the last link.